# How can I join the 2nd process which has exited while 1st process is still running?

Tags: python-2.7, python-multiprocessing

Partial code:

```
p1 = Process(target1, args1)
p2 = Process(target2, args2)

p1.start()
p2.start()

p1.join()
p2.join()
```

There is a good chance that any process might be interrupted; hence I should not be joining sequentially as join is a blocking call.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on your intention - `Process.join()` is used when you want to wait for the selected process to finish (so it 'joins' back to the main process), but you can always check your process status in a loop instead of waiting for one to finish before the second finishes.

I'd recommend using `multiprocessing.Event` and passing that to your process, then your process can set the flag when it exits and you can do an event loop in your main process waiting for that event to be sure that the process exited. You can also use the same system to order your processes to exit.

You can also loop through your processes with a `timeout` set to  `Process.join()` if all you want is to identify when a process ended without waiting on the previous process, something like:

```
import multiprocessing
import time

def target(name, timeout=5):
    print("{} started...".format(name))
    time.sleep(timeout)
    print("{} finishing...".format(name))

# define a process list for convenience with initialization/shutdown:
processes = {
    "P1": {"target": target, "args": ["P1", 5]},
    "P2": {"target": target, "args": ["P2", 3]},
    "P3": {"target": target, "args": ["P3", 8]},
    "P4": {"target": target, "args": ["P4", 1]},
}

if __name__ == "__main__":   # cross-platform multiprocessing guard
    # initialize and start our processes:
    for name, kwargs in processes.items():  # loop through the process list
        print("Initializing: {}...".format(name))
        processes[name] = multiprocessing.Process(**kwargs)
        print("Starting: {}...".format(name))
        processes[name].start()

    # when its time to exit...
    processes = processes.items()  # easier to manage as a list of tuples
    while processes:  # loop for as long as we have alive processes...
        name, process = processes.pop(0)  # remove the first element from our process list
        process.join(0.1)  # trying to join the current process, wait for 100ms
        if process.is_alive():  # Process still alive, moving to the next one...
            processes.append((name, process))  # add it to the back of the queue
        else:
            print("{} ended!".format(name))
    print("Woo-hoo! All processes exited...")
```

NOTE: This will work without asking to 'join' your subprocess to the main process in this case, but if your subprocess waits for a task without calling join (essentially `wait()`) it will never close. But, again, that's why you'd want to use `multiprocessing.Event` in the first case.